# CSS background of a fieldset

Tags: html, css

At the website I'm currently working on I need to differentiate some elements by giving them background (color) so it's easier to see which one you're in.
If I use the inspector from firefox, I can give the background without problem but when I pass that to my code I don't know why it does not work.
The class I'm using is this one:

```
<fieldset class="collapsible required-fields group-desc-programa field-group-fieldset form-wrapper collapse-processed">
</fieldset>
```

So what I add in my css style-sheet is the following:

```
.collapsible.required-fields.group-desc-programa.field-group-fieldset.form-wrapper.collapse-processed.collapsed{
  background: red !important;
}
```

I think it has to be a really easy question because I normally do this kind of things without problem...

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last class `.collapsed` is not necessary:

```
.collapsible.required-fields.group-desc-programa.field-group-fieldset.form-wrapper.collapse-processed {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some `,`.

```
.collapsible, .required-fields, .group-desc-programa, .field-group-fieldset, .form-wrapper, .collapse-processed, .collapsed{
    background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css code

```
.collapsible, .required-fields, .group-desc-programa, .field-group-fieldset, .form-wrapper, .collapse-processed, .collapsed{
background: red !important;
}
```

If you want to apply background color to the particular fieldset mentioned in question. Use id to apply background to it.